# do a getter for an object?

Tags: c++

My Game class is composed of a Spaceship.
I put the Spaceship object private and I did a getter for this object.

```
Spaceship Game::getSpaceShip() const
{
    return mySpaceship;
}
```

When I use my spaceship object via my getter in my main, it does not work properly. If I put it public and just use it by it's name, it works. Do you have an idea what could be causing this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work properly"?

Comment: It does not have the same behavior than when I use it without the getter. For example, game.mySpaceship.modifyPosition(key);
will work properly compared to game.getMySpaceship.modifyPosition(key);

Comment: You probably need to return a reference or a pointer..

Comment: @Brendan Long Really? Can you explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning mySpaceship copy. Try to return pointer to mySpaceship object.

```
Spaceship *Game::getSpaceShip()
{
    return &mySpaceship;
}
```

Or reference:

```
const Spaceship& Game::getSpaceShip() const
{
    return mySpaceship;
}
```

It's not Java. In C++ you are passing and returning variables by value! Unless you indicate that you want to do it differently (by pointer or reference).

And if you need to modify returned reference.

```
Spaceship& Game::getSpaceShip()
{
    return mySpaceship;
}
```

Comment: Probably a bad idea to return a non-const reference to a data member from a const method.

Comment: Your first suggestion gives me this error message: return value type does not match the function type. Il will try the second suggestion.
(I did exactly like you did and it does make sense, but I don't know why I get this error)

Comment: Yes juan is right, if I return a constant it works, but I can't modify the object anymore..

Comment: I need to be able to modify my spaceship object.

Comment: So change function signature to non const. Remember to change it in header also.

Comment: @Maxwell then you need to add a non-const version of the method: `Spaceship& getSpaceShip();`

Comment: I would like to, but if I don't do: const Spaceship& getSpaceShip();
I get the error message: return value type does not match the function type. It won't let me return a non-constant pointer. And yes, I changed it in both .h and .cpp.

Comment: Oh I had to take off the const at the end of the prototype also. It's weird because I'm not really modifying my object in the method. Anyways, it works. Thank you!

Comment: The issue is that given a const reference to Game, you shouldn't be able to get a non-const reference to its members. That's why the const-qualified method can't return a non-const reference.

Answer (score 4):

Your method

```
Spaceship Game::getSpaceShip() const;
```

returns a `Spaceship` *by value*. This means that the caller gets *their own* `Spaceship` instance, which is initialized from `mySpaceship`.

As yattering says, you should return a reference to the object if you want the caller used the same instance.

Now, the two accessor methods I'd expect to see are:

```
Spaceship const& getSpaceship() const { return mySpaceship; }
Spaceship&       getSpaceship()       { return mySpaceship; }
```

The first returns a *reference to a const `Spaceship`*: you can't modify the ship through this reference, but multiple callers can view the same state, if they only have a const reference to the game itself.

The second returns a *reference to `Spaceship`*: this is full read-write access, but you need a non-const reference to the Game to get it.

---

If it helps, consider something simpler than a spaceship:

```
class Wrapper {
    int value;

public:
    int        copy_of_value()            const { return value; }
    int&       reference_to_value()             { return value; }
    int const& const_reference_to_value() const { return value; }
};
```

Now, these all behave differently:

```
Wrapper w;
int i = w.copy_of_value();
i += 1; // changes i but not w.value

int& j = w.reference_to_value();
j += 1; // does change w.value

int const& k = w.const_reference_to_value();
k += 1; // won't even compile
```

Note that if I only had a const reference to `w` in the first place, I could call the two const-qualified methods but not `reference_to_value`, so the const prevents me from changing `w.value`.

Comment: In `reference_to_value` you are missing `()`.