# Getter for an object

Tags: c++-cli

I have a problem very similar to one already answered in here: [do a getter for an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604127/do-a-getter-for-an-object) It does not really help me in c++/cli since ordinary references and pointers won't work. What do I do?

My Character class includes a Statistics object. I need something like

```
Statistics Character::getStatistics()
{
return characterStatistics;
}
```

yet I'm getting
E0334   class "Statistics" has no suitable copy constructor
C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'Statistics' to 'Statistics'

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor or copy move constructor for Statistics?  That is what that error is saying, you don't have `Statistics(Statistics stat)` defined.

Comment: It is absolutely crucial to understand when to use the ^ hat, you can't get far with C++/CLI if that is murky.  Hat required here, it is an object and not a struct.  Roughly equivalent to `*` in native C++.  You'd (almost) never do that because of the dangling pointer problem but life is easy with a garbage collector.  No rule-of-three or rule-of-five, just the rule-of-one: use the hat for reference types.

Comment: I tried adding copy constructor as @snb suggested and it worked for now, I am not sure if I won't ruin this later.

Comment: @Ðаn unfortunately the assignement explicitely says to use C++/CLI